# html5 input type date datalist remove other options

Tags: javascript, html, css

I set `datalist` in `input[type='date']`.

For e.g.,

```html
<input type="date" id="date" name="date" list="thesedates">

<datalist id="thesedates">

    <option label="Groundhog Day">2014-02-02</option>

    <option label="Valentine's Day">2014-02-14</option>

    <option label="Flag Day">2014-06-14</option>

</datalist>
```

**Question**

In this example i seen **Other** option. I want to remove this.

Thank you for help me !

Comment: what is wrong with snippet you've shared? there is no `Other` option

Comment: if you want your your to select from list of selected dates then use only dropdown list, (`<select> <option>`)

Comment: @marmeladze It is there , I can see that, after clicking down arrow from the date box.

Comment: It's because you're using input type date. The labels are used to select a particular date, but users can enter any other date.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to pick date only from given list. Why are you not using **select** element?

```
<form action="index.php">
  <select name="date">
      <option value="2014-02-02">Groundhog Day</option>
      <option value="2014-02-14">Valentine's Day</option>
      <option value="2014-06-14">Flag Day</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```